# Unique Values from multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 5 different spreadsheets storing telephone numbers and names. They all look like this:

```
Name     Telephone
--------------
name1    551
name2    552
name1    551
name5    555
```

(There are thousands of records in each spreadsheet)

I would like a sixth spreadsheet to bring all of these together, showing no duplicated values (so 1* name 1) and 1*name 5. However duplicates can be in several spreadsheets, for example name 1 could occur in all 5 spreadsheets.

Any suggestions??

Comment: If they were in different worksheets within the same workbook then this would be possible using worksheet formulas alone, but since we are talking about different workbooks, this will be practically unfeasible without recourse to VBA. Just to let you know in case you were hoping for a purely formula-based solution.

Comment: @xorlx It is possible in a difficult way purely with formulas only (did it before). But it may even be easier to combine all the lists together into sheet 6 and run a filter on them to hide the duplicates, then copy this new list to the side (If the five first sheets will never be modified).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the VBA method. Code is not that difficult, in case it is ok to use VBA for you.
Insert a new sheet before the first sheet. Press Alt + F11 and copy paste the below code.

and Press F5 to merge all contacts in 5 sheets to sheet1 and remove duplicates. 
Imp Note: Take a backup of your excel workbook before executing this code.

```
Sub Combine_and_Remove_Duplicates()
Output_Row = 2

For Sheet_Index = 2 To 6
    Input_Row = 2
    While Sheets(Sheet_Index).Cells(Input_Row, 1) <> ""
        Sheets(1).Cells(Output_Row, 1) = Sheets(Sheet_Index).Cells(Input_Row, 1)
        Sheets(1).Cells(Output_Row, 2) = Sheets(Sheet_Index).Cells(Input_Row, 2)
        Output_Row = Output_Row + 1
        Input_Row = Input_Row + 1
    Wend
Next Sheet_Index

Sheets(1).Columns("A:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header _
    :=xlYes

End Sub
```